# How to delete local file with fs.unlink?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

**CODE:**

```
fs.unlink("/public/images/uploads/"+req.file.filename, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("failed to delete local image:"+err);
        } else {
            console.log('successfully deleted local image');                                
        }
});
```

---

**ERROR MESSAGE IN CONSOLE/TERMINAL:**

```
failed to delete local image:Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/public/images/uploads/ed6d810405e42d0dfd03d7668e356db3'
```

---

**SITUATION**

I must have specified the wrong path. I don't understand why it would be wrong, the "`public`" folder is at the same level as the "`app.js`" file. The "`upload.js`" is in a folder called "`routes`" which is at the same level as "`app.js`".

And I have specified a route "/public" to my public folder in my app.js:

```
//Static Folder
app.use("/public",express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/public")));
```

---

**QUESTION:**

What have I done wrong ?

Comment: This file really exists? In the error description it haven't extension. That's not exactly a problem, but a little uncommon

Comment: @RômuloM.Farias Yes, it's an image saved in binary.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I bet you want to delete file inside project directory. Try with this (dot before "/"):

```
fs.unlink("./public/images/uploads/"+req.file.filename, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("failed to delete local image:"+err);
        } else {
            console.log('successfully deleted local image');                                
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a part of the path. What you're showing is not enough, but it can be fixed in the following way:

For example, the path I got of a file is the following:

```
 'C:\001-Training\MEANCourse\http:\localhost:3000\images\1-1571080310351.jpeg'
```

But actually the path is

```
 'C:\001-Training\MEANCourse\http:\localhost:3000\backend\images\1-1571080310351.jpeg'
```

Here, the "MEANCourse" is my project name, and "backend" is the top-level folder name as "src", but **when the path was produced automatically, the top-level folder was ignored**.

So I added "backend" to the path, and it started to work.

You have to find out what part is missing in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `c:\` for you may not be in the windows environment. Also, you may be finally executing this in cloud etc. Instead, use a relative directory by using `__dirname`. Like, if using backtick, do `${__dirname}` then add the rest of the directory, relative to the javascript file your code is in.